# Python json.dump produces file of size zero bytes

Tags: python, json, dictionary

At some stage in my code, I need to dump a python dictionary into a json file. Here is the code that does that:

```
def output_batch(self, batch):
    with open(os.path.join(self.get_current_job_directory(), 'batch_' + str(self.index) + '.json'), 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(batch, json_file, sort_keys = True, indent = 4, separators = (',', ': '))
    exit()
```

Here `self.index` is a unique integer index that identifies this specific instance. `self.get_current_job_directory()` returns the path to were the file should be created.

Logging the length of the dictionary just before dumping it returns `42691`. However the output file has a size of zero bytes. This doesn't really make any sense. Even in case of an empty dict the file would be 2 bytes long (to compensate for the `{}`).

The code is part of a highly parallelized map-reduce style pipeline and is almost impossible to reproduce here. Now there are a million things that can go wrong in such a setup, but no other thread has access to the `dict` being dumped and no other thread would access the same output file.

*** Update: The process exits (by calling `exit()`) right after this function call, maybe has got something to do with this?

Any suggestion or ideas on why this might happen?

Comment: Might be obvious but did you print(json_file) and double check that you are indeed writing to the right file?

Comment: @kshikama Yes. I am 100 percent sure that's not the problem.

Comment: Are you able to write "Hello World" or anything random into that file from the line right before you try your json dump?

Comment: @kshikama I still get files with 0 size for some instances.

Comment: If possible, I would try opening the file in `"x"` mode. If you then get errors, it might help to debug it further.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the `with` context isn't being exited correctly being at the end of the function. Try to close the file explicitly.

```
def output_batch(self, batch):
    json_file = open(...):
    json.dump(batch, json_file, sort_keys = True, indent = 4, separators = (',', ': '))
    json_file.close()
```

Moreover, make sure you call `open('w')` with writing permissions, and that you have permissions to write to that place.